# Print `errno` name instead of value in GDB

Tags: gdb, errno

I wonder if there is any way to print `errno` symbolic name instead of just a number in GDB. For example, instead of

```
errno = 13
```

I would like to see something like

```
EACCES
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have a recent GDB with embedded Python, you can use the Python interpreter to do what you want.

The following (untested) code should be about right:

```
(gdb) python import errno
(gdb) python print errno.errorcode[13]
```

You should be able to define a python command, e.g. `perrno`, that will cut down on typing. Documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Commands-In-Python.html#Commands-In-Python).